# why my AsyncTask class isnt debugged?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

i have a problem with android application that contain a AsyncTask. When i try to debug it androidStudio bring me to a section of comments of asynctask. i don't understand if this problem is caused by problem on library or if the problem is on the logic of costruction: i have a class that

-fetch an integer from UI then

-lunch asynctask that connect to a server and receive the data (put its on a variable), then

-redraw the ui and set out the data on a textview

**like the code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    LinearLayout spazioGen;
    TextView[] cell;
    LinearLayout[] rows;
    LinearLayout def;
    LinearLayout solution;
    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private EditText textField;
    private TextView serverOut;
    private Button button;
    private String messsage;
    private String inputLine;
    private Integer dimensionChoosed = 10;
    private String word1 = "";
    private String word2 = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dimension);    
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findCenter);            

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                messsage = textField.getText().toString();    // get the text message on the text field
                textField.setText("");                        // Reset the text field to blank
                dimensionChoosed = Integer.parseInt(messsage.toString());
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
                createGriglia();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createGriglia(Integer dimensionChoosed)
    {
        int i,j;
        spazioGen = new LinearLayout(this);
        spazioGen.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        spazioGen.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        spazioGen.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_ext));
        spazioGen.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        //create an array of textview to fillup with data received from server

        setContentView(spazioGen);
    }

    private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                client = new Socket("192.168.0.104", 4444); // connect to the server
                printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                printwriter.println(messsage); // write the message to output stream
                printwriter.flush();

                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
                String message = "";


                while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null && !(message.equals("flag")))
                {
                    word1 = message;
                    //do stuff with data received
                }

                while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    word2 = message;
                    //do stuff with data received
                }

                inputStreamReader.close();
                System.out.println(message);
                printwriter.close();
                client.close(); // closing the connection

            } catch (UnknownHostException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            createGriglia(dimensionChoosed);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Delete your app from your device. Clean your project and install the app again and see if it helps you.

Comment: No changes for clean project... now i try to reboot and install last version of android studio...

Comment: Does the debugger pause the app if you put a breakpoint on line `client = new Socket("192.168.0.104", 4444);`? Does the exception get caught in any of the `catch` blocks in `doInBackground`? What type of problem are you getting?

Comment: when i try to step in the SendMessage class (i use AndroidStudio) debugger "land" on the comment of AsyncTask superclass. So i will never reach the "client = new Socket("192.168.0.104", 4444);" row.

Comment: Delete your app, clean and rebuild project, Goog Luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to everybody who helps me.

I solved this problem installing latest version of android studio.

I hope this can help who got my same problem